# Rails Custom SQL Query not working with find_by_sql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, find-by-sql

I have three Tables users, user_groups and user_groups_users in my Rails Application. Now, I have written an SQL query

```
SELECT user_group_id FROM user_groups_users GROUP BY user_group_id HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN user_id IN (1,4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)
```

to extract those user_group_id, which exactly has the user_ids provided by the input. In this case 1,4 would be provided as an ruby array [1,4].

Now, i want to write this SQL query for my rails application. But when I execute this query using `find_by_sql` statement in rails,it is returning me the correct no. of user_groups in which the particular user_ids belong, but the result does not show the user_group_id.

`=> [#<UserGroup >, #<UserGroup >, #<UserGroup >, #<UserGroup >, #<UserGroup >, #<UserGroup >]`

so how can i extract User_group_id from it.

However, when I execute the query by connecting directly to the database. I am getting the desired results

`sql = "SELECT user_group_id FROM user_groups_users WHERE user_id IN (1,2) GROUP BY user_group_id HAVING Count(DISTINCT user_id) = 2;"`

`records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`

But, here the problem is, how would I use the String replacement technique, to use the user_ids given as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting array of the object so you need to iterate loop over it

```
user_groups_users = [#<UserGroup >, #<UserGroup >, #<UserGroup >, #<UserGroup >, #<UserGroup >, #<UserGroup >]

user_groups_users.map do |user_groups_user|
  puts user_groups_user.user_group_id
end
```

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if it works for you.So, other can understand what is the correct answer.